# Is it possible to create a universal hyperlink in excel for windows and mac without programming

Tags: excel, windows, macos

Is it possible to make one hyperlink to a folder or files in an excel cell for Windows and MacOS ?

Tried starting from paths smb:\ and file:\\ on Windows, similar on Mac, e.g. \192.168.100.60

Comment: if the actual directory structure is the same then all you need to do is to change the differences which are standard.

Comment: I know you said "without programming", but with programming, this is what you can use: `Range("A2").Value = Application.OperatingSystem`.

Comment: @Dominique =INFO("system") will return "mac" or "pcdos"

Comment: @user11222393: wrap that inside an `IF()` formula, write it as an answer and your reputation might increase :-)

Answer (score 3):

With `INFO`: [info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/info-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) you can find weather it is Windows or Mac OS.

`=INFO("system")` will return "pcdos" or "mac" dependently on your system.

Use it with `IF` or `SWITCH`:

```
=HYPERLINK(IF(INFO("system")="pcdos","path_to_windows_file","path_to_mac_file"),"Link_name")

=HYPERLINK(SWITCH(INFO("system"),"pcdos","path_to_windows_file","mac","path_to_mac_file"),"Link_name")
```

Further you can wrap it with `IFERROR` as `INFO` is not available in web versions:

Note that `INFO` is not available in web versions.